# How to run a function on a scheduler with clokwerk?

Tags: rust, scheduler

I've been trying to run a scheduler in Rust using the [clokwerk](https://crates.io/crates/clokwerk) crate. I copied a bit of the code in the docs and tried to run it but it doesn't work for me. It compiles fine but I expect to see "Periodic task" logged to the console every 10 secs which doesn't happen.

```
use clokwerk::{Scheduler, TimeUnits};

fn main() {
    let mut scheduler = Scheduler::with_tz(chrono::Utc);

    scheduler
        .every(10.seconds())
        .run(|| println!("Periodic task"));
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What doesn't work? Does it compile? If you get any errors, edit them into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scheduler.every(...).run(...)` doesn't execute the task, it just registers the task with the scheduler. To actually instruct the scheduler to run tasks, you need to repeatedly call [run_pending()](https://docs.rs/clokwerk/latest/clokwerk/struct.Scheduler.html#method.run_pending) in a loop, as shown in the example in the docs:

```rust
loop {
    scheduler.run_pending();
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
}
```

Comment: Note there is also a [watch_thread()](https://docs.rs/clokwerk/latest/clokwerk/struct.Scheduler.html#method.watch_thread) method that you could use to spawn a background thread to do the same thing.